# Why does my Google Maps Geocoding API not work when my API key is restricted?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have functionality on my web page that changes depending on if the user has allowed location services. If they do not, the page shows a map from google maps center on one of my business' locations. If they do, I get the user's location and have the map show a direction line between the user and the business' location.

This was all working fine before I restricted my API key to my website. After I did, when the user has location services on, the code to find their location no longer works (in which I use the geocode API) and the space where the map would be is just blank. When the key is restricted and the user has location services turned off, the map still shows correctly.

The below code is what I use to find the user's location. When I have the API restricted, I get this error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address_components')".

So I've found the issue but don't know why it's only happening when I restrict the API key.

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var long = position.coords.longitude;
                var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&key=*my actual key is here in my code*";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var results = msg.results;
                        console.log(results);
                        var postCode = 0;
                        var cityName = "Parts Unknown";
                        results[0].address_components.forEach(entry => {
                            if (entry.types?.[0] === "postal_code") {
                                postCode = entry.long_name
                            }
                        })
                        results[0].address_components.forEach(entry => {
                            if (entry.types?.[0] === "locality") {
                                cityName = entry.long_name
                            }
                        })
                        memberLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        memberLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch/issues/269